# Where is the mistake in my HTTP form login program?

Tags: java, html, http, post, authentication

I am trying to view a protected html page by posting the login values with the http request... The site is sportguru.co.uk and I cannot seem to correctly post the password!? When I run this code (with my actual login details):

```
/**
 *  $Id: LoginByHttpPost.java 101 2010-03-13 23:52:31Z oneyour $
 * 
 * This is an accompanying program for the article
 * http://www.1your.com/drupal/LoginToWebsiteByHTTPPOSTCodeListing
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2009 - 2010 www.1your.com.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of www.1your.com nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 */

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LoginByHttpPost
{
    private static final String POST_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    private static final String LOGIN_ACTION_NAME = "Log in";
    private static final String LOGIN_USER_NAME_PARAMETER_NAME = "email";
    private static final String LOGIN_PASSWORD_PARAMETER_NAME = "password";

    private static final String LOGIN_USER_NAME = "emailAddress";
    private static final String LOGIN_PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://www.sportguru.co.uk/login_form.asp";

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("About to run the 'LogInByHttpPost' downloaded from www.1Your.com");
        LoginByHttpPost httpUrlBasicAuthentication = new LoginByHttpPost();
        httpUrlBasicAuthentication.httpPostLogin();
    }

    /**
     * The single public method of this class that
     * 1. Prepares a login message
     * 2. Makes the HTTP POST to the target URL
     * 3. Reads and returns the response
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * Any problems while doing the above.
     *
     */
    public void httpPostLogin ()
    {
        try
        {
            // Prepare the content to be written
            // throws UnsupportedEncodingException
            String urlEncodedContent = preparePostContent(LOGIN_USER_NAME, LOGIN_PASSWORD);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = doHttpPost(TARGET_URL, urlEncodedContent);

            String response = readResponse(urlConnection);

            System.out.println("Successfully made the HTPP POST.");
            System.out.println("Recevied response is: '/n" + response + "'");

            System.out.println("/n Hope you found the article and this sample program useful./nPlease leave your feed back at www.1your.com and support us.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.println("Problems encounterd.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Using the given username and password, and using the static string variables, prepare
     * the login message. Note that the username and password will encoded to the
     * UTF-8 standard.
     *
     * @param loginUserName
     * The user name for login
     *
     * @param loginPassword
     * The password for login
     *
     * @return
     * The complete login message that can be HTTP Posted
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * Any problems during URL encoding
     */
    private String preparePostContent(String loginUserName, String loginPassword) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Encode the user name and password to UTF-8 encoding standard
        // throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        String encodedLoginUserName = URLEncoder.encode(loginUserName, "UTF-8");
        String encodedLoginPassword = URLEncoder.encode(loginPassword, "UTF-8");

        String content = "Log in=" + LOGIN_ACTION_NAME +" &" + LOGIN_USER_NAME_PARAMETER_NAME +"="
        + encodedLoginUserName + "&" + LOGIN_PASSWORD_PARAMETER_NAME + "=" + encodedLoginPassword;

        return content;

    }

    /**
     * Makes a HTTP POST to the target URL by using an HttpURLConnection.
     *
     * @param targetUrl
     * The URL to which the HTTP POST is made.
     *
     * @param content
     * The contents which will be POSTed to the target URL.
     *
     * @return
     * The open URLConnection which can be used to read any response.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public HttpURLConnection doHttpPost(String targetUrl, String content) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        try
        {
            // Open a connection to the target URL
            // throws IOException
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(targetUrl).openConnection());

            // Specifying that we intend to use this connection for input
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            // Specifying that we intend to use this connection for output
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            // Specifying the content type of our post
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", POST_CONTENT_TYPE);

            // Specifying the method of HTTP request which is POST
            // throws ProtocolException
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Prepare an output stream for writing data to the HTTP connection
            // throws IOException
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            // throws IOException
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(content);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            return urlConnection;
        }
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.println("I/O problems while trying to do a HTTP post.");
            ioException.printStackTrace();

            // Good practice: clean up the connections and streams
            // to free up any resources if possible
            if (dataOutputStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                }
                catch(Throwable ignore)
                {
                    // Cannot do anything about problems while
                    // trying to clean up. Just ignore
                }
            }
            if (urlConnection != null)
            {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            // throw the exception so that the caller is aware that
            // there was some problems
            throw ioException;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read response from the URL connection
     *
     * @param urlConnection
     * The URLConncetion from which the response will be read
     *
     * @return
     * The response read from the URLConnection
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * When problems encountered during reading the response from the
     * URLConnection.
     */
    private String readResponse(HttpURLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try
        {
            // Prepare a reader to read the response from the URLConnection
            // throws IOException
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String responeLine;

            // Good Practice: Use StringBuilder in this case
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            // Read untill there is nothing left in the stream
            // throws IOException
            while ((responeLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append('\n'+responeLine);
            }

            return response.toString();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.println("Problems while reading the response");
            ioException.printStackTrace();

            // throw the exception so that the caller is aware that
            // there was some problems
            throw ioException;

        }
        finally
        {
            // Good practice: clean up the connections and streams
            // to free up any resources if possible
            if (bufferedReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // throws IOException
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                catch(Throwable ignore)
                {
                    // Cannot do much with exceptions doing clean up
                    // Ignoring all exceptions
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The HTML page I receive contains this form:

```
<form name="loginPage" method="post" action="login.asp" onSubmit="return submitForm()" style="margin:0px;padding:0px">
    <input type="hidden" name="pageReferer" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="logintype" value="page" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pagePoolCode" value="" />

<div style="border:2px solid #666666;width:486px">
    <div style="background-image:url(home/images/structure/header_login.gif);height:28px;"></div>
    <div style="padding:7px;">
        <table cellspacing="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="62">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pageEmail" value="emailAddress" size="32"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pagePassword" size="32"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"></td>
            <td class="small"><a href="forgotten.asp"><strong>Forgotten</strong> your email address or password? Or has your<br /><strong>email changed</strong> since last you used the site? <strong>Click here</strong> &raquo;</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="padding-top:7px;"><input type="image" src="/home/images/buttons/login.gif" value="Log in"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

As can be seen the email address is posted into the form correctly. But I wish to view the source of the html page after the post... Do I need cookies or something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the HTTP status codes? There may be a redirection.

Comment: No I have not, how could I do this?

Comment: You would call `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` to see if it is [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). You can then check the location header of the response for the URL to the redirect. However, if its redirecting, you can just instruct your client to follow the redirect automatically by calling `urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean true)`.

Comment: It says response code 200, and I automated the following of redirects but it still wont work!? The Post is working with the email address, as it turns up in the returned html but maybe not the password... Would you give it a go? I am really perplexed here...

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = "Log in=" + LOGIN_ACTION_NAME +" &" + LOGIN_USER_NAME_PARAMETER_NAME +"="
   + encodedLoginUserName + "&" + LOGIN_PASSWORD_PARAMETER_NAME + "=" + encodedLoginPassword;
```

Are you that there really should be a space in `Log in`?

Maybe `Log%20in` or `Log+in` would be better here. (As I don't see your complete form, I can only guess here.)

---

So, we have to send these form fields:

- `pageReferer` (empty)
- `logintype` (`page`)
- `pagePoolCode` (empty)
- `pageEmail`  (an email address?)
- `pagePassword` (a password?)

There also is a `<input type="image" src="/home/images/buttons/login.gif" value="Log in">` - but this has no *name* attribute, so it can't be sent. So, my first guess would be simply omitting this `"Log in="` part in your content string.

```
String content = LOGIN_USER_NAME_PARAMETER_NAME + "="
   + encodedLoginUserName + "&" + LOGIN_PASSWORD_PARAMETER_NAME + "=" + encodedLoginPassword;
```

If this doesn't work, add the first three fields also to the string:

```
String content = "pageReferer=&loginType=page&pagePoolCode=&" + 
    LOGIN_USER_NAME_PARAMETER_NAME + "="
   + encodedLoginUserName + "&" + LOGIN_PASSWORD_PARAMETER_NAME + "=" + encodedLoginPassword;
```

Comment: Interesting, I will report back... Thank you!

Comment: @Freddie: Please add it to the question, not a comment.

Comment: I cannot include the entire form in this EditText, but if you see sportguru.co.uk/login_form.asp and inspect the form you will see that there is an imageButton "Login" with value = "Log in"... I tried what you advised but to no avail, thanks anyway for your time

Comment: It is all there, there is a slight problem with the formatting, i.e. "Seeing this login page a lot?"

Comment: I think I fixed the HTML source formatting. (I removed the duplicate.) For the future, make sure you indent all source code by four spaces, and let an empty line before.

Comment: @FreddieH: I added some recommendations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendations, I have learned a lot! They did not work however, I think potentially the loginType parameter is key... But of course I can not figure out how to unlock it! The password is simply not being sent, or else it is and it needs to be encoded differently, or else one or all of the three first fields also need values assigned! Thanks again, I will continue tinkering!